# PHP problem with date format and strange errors

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to work on 2 errors.

The first one is the date: it shows a very rare date format: "Fecha de vuelta: 1637794800". It should show the date you put + 10 days.

The second one are the 2 things Visual Studio Code says are wrong: `.length` and `isNaN`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>lapuente_de la pena_blanca_ModuloDWES_TareaEvaluativa02.php</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        if (isset($_GET['enviar'])) {

            if (isset($_GET['fechaalquiler']) && ($_GET['fechaalquiler']!==null) && ($_GET['fechaalquiler']!=='')) {
                echo "Fecha de vuelta: ".gmdate(strtotime($_GET['fechaalquiler']."+ 10 days"))."<br/>";      // XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            } else {echo "Fecha no introducida <br/>";}

            if (isset($_GET['dni']) && ($_GET['dni']!==null) && ($_GET['dni']!=='') && substr("TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKEO", (int)(substr(($_GET['dni']), 0, 8)) % 23, 1)==substr(($_GET['dni']), 8, 1)) {
                echo "DNI correcto";
            } else if (!$_GET['dni']) {
                echo "DNI no introducido";
            } else if ($_GET['dni'].length!==9 || isNaN(substr(($_GET['dni']), 0, 8))) {    // XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                echo "DNI incorrecto";
            } else {
                echo "DNI incorrecto; la letra correcta sería ".substr("TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKEO", (int)(substr(($_GET['dni']), 0, 8)) % 23, 1);
            }
            
        } ?>
             <form name="input" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="get">

                <label for="Fecha alquiler">Fecha alquiler</label>
                <input name="fechaalquiler" type="date">
                <?php echo "<br/>"?>

                <label for="DNI">DNI</label>
                <input name="dni" type="text">
                <br />

                <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="enviar"/>            
             </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `1637794800` is a timestamp. If you convert it back with the `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1637794800)`, you get "2021-11-24 18:00:00"

Comment: `.length` is Javascript (maybe Python) notation. `isNaN` doesn't exist in PHP, there is `is_nan()`

Comment: `.length` and `isNaN` are javascript functions, not PHP. This will give you strange errors.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments, I could resolve the questions

For the first error: `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_GET['fechaalquiler']."+ 10 days"))`

For the second errors: `strlen($_GET['dni'])!==9` and `!is_numeric(substr(($_GET['dni']), 0, 8))`